Azure CLI is not able to connenct to Azure DevOps
I want to connect my Azure CLI(CloudShell on azure portal) to Azure DevOps to create variable groups. But I'm getting this error when i execute
$token = <PAT Token of my ADO Project>
$token | az devops login --org "https://dev.azure.com/my-project/"`

Below is error:
Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
I'm expecting to connect my Azure CLI to Azure DevOps and create variable groups over there by using Azure CLI.
My Azure CLI version is 2.59.0.
I Installed the extension azure-devops as well. But still same issue.
az extension add --name azure-devops

I have the impression that is just a warning. What happens when you try to execute a command right after the login?

I'm entering the below command after getting baove error:
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id 4 --name requires-login --value True --output table --project Portfolio --org https://dev.azure.com/<Org-Name>/ 
Then I'm getting below error
The requested resource requires user authentication: https://dev.azure.com/<Org-Name//_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/4

Strange. I've run similar commands many times and I've seen that warning, but that never prevented me to run other commands. Consider using an environment variable as suggested by Shamrai

Hi @suryaTeja, May I know if the answer by @ShamraiAleksander to use the environment variable of AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT can resolve your issue? Thx.

Hi @Alvin Zhao, it's working by using AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT

Check the example with AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT variable for PowerShell: Use the AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT environment variable
# set environment variable for current process
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxx'


Thanks @aleksander, this working for me. But I'm just curious to know is there way to create variable groups in ADO via azure pipeline CLI Task without using PAT Token for authentication ?

$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = "<PAT>"
az pipelines variable-group create --name basic-grp --variables xyz=123 --org <org URL> --project <Proj name>
Above commands are working fine, but I want to know how to do that without using PAT, in Azure DeVOps pipeline.

@suryaTeja The az devops module supports only PAT and it works through REST API. You may try to use REST API through Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0 ; Variablegroups - Add. But it would be a more complex way.
